# How we can open apple watch settings when clicked a button?

Tags: watchkit

I made an independent watch app, for getting data from healthkit, and users can edit permission to allow them to collect some health data.

Do we have any method to open apple watch settings when clicking a button?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: nope, I have to write instructions for the user go to the apple watch setting to update permission